# Regular tetrahedron inscribed in sphere.

Tags: trigonometry

A regular tetrahedron with edges of length 2a is inscribed in a sphere. Find the diameter of the sphere. 
According to my textbook the answer is $a\sqrt6$ I cannot see how this is derived.

Comment: The edges of the tetrahedron are the diagonals or the faces of the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edges of the tetrahedron are the diagonals or the faces of the cube.